# How do I expand the view of the camera to take up the entire screen (like snapchat)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, camera

I am trying to make an app that opens on a camera view that takes up the entire screen and has buttons that overlay the camera's view. However, my code right now only provides me with a view that takes up a section of the middle of the screen. How can I adjust the following code to take up the entire view?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var photoPreviewImageView: UIImageView!
    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      session = AVCaptureSession()
        session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        let backCamera =  AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
      var error: NSError?
      var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
      do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera!)
      } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
      }
      if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {
        session!.addInput(input)
        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:  AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput!) {
            session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session!)
            videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity =    AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation =   AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
          photoPreviewImageView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
          session!.startRunning()
       }
     }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        videoPreviewLayer!.frame = photoPreviewImageView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use an UIImageView. Add the videoPreviewLayer to your ViewController view.

Comment: how would I implement this? I am still new to Swift and Xcode @LeoDabus

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your preview layer as a uiimage view. Make it a view and manually size it to the entire view controller

Inside view will appear where you set the frame of the preview layer. Change the code

Set the bounds to = self.view.bounds

Edit ——-

Change the gravity you have set from aspect fit aspect fill

Edit —- 
Try setting the frame with = self.view.frame.bounds

Make sure your preview layer is sized to take up the entire view controller

Make sure your preview layer and the video preview layer are set to aspect fill

You can try this 
    self.view.addsubview(videopreviewlayer)

Or have it set to the appropriate layer

If none of these work please share your interface builder (storyboard) maybe there is an issue with your view heirarchy

Comment: This didn't change anything, do you have any other advice?

Comment: Oh ! The gravity you have set change it to aspect fill

Comment: I tried this and there is still no change, any other suggestions? I will take whatever help I can get. Thanks!